# Error: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response

Tags: firebase, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, firebase-storage

Please help me out, I'm trying to save and Image to firebase storage and also save the URL info to my user's information but every time I select an Image and I click the save button, I'm getting errors. Please find attached the code;

[The[TheViewModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulnXw.jpg) repository impl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muQF3.jpg).
This is the viewModel;
@HiltViewModel
class SharedViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val userDataRepository: UserDataRepository,
//    private val storage: FirebaseStorage
) : ViewModel() {

```
private val _userDataState = Channel<AboutState>()
val userDataState = _userDataState.receiveAsFlow()

private val _newUserData = mutableStateOf(NewUserData())
val newUserData: State<NewUserData> = _newUserData


// Function to save a new USer Details
fun saveData(
    userData: UserData, imageUri: Uri
) = viewModelScope.launch {

    try {

        val imageUploadDeferred = async {
            userDataRepository.addImageToFirebaseStorage(imageUri)
        }
        val imageUploadResult = imageUploadDeferred.await()

        if (imageUploadResult is Resource.Success) {
            userDataRepository.saveData(userData).collect { result ->

                // Now you can proceed to save the rest of the data
                when (result) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        _userDataState.send(AboutState(isSuccess = "Data Added successfully"))
                    }

                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        _userDataState.send(AboutState(isLoading = true))
                    }

                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        _userDataState.send(AboutState(isError = result.message))
                    }
                }

            }

        } else {
            // Handle the case where image upload failed
            _userDataState.send(AboutState(isError = "Image upload failed: ${imageUploadResult.message}"))
            Log.e("Upload", "Error: ${imageUploadResult.message}")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // Handle any exceptions that may occur during the process
        _userDataState.send(AboutState(isError = e.message))
        Log.e("Error", "Error: ${e.message}")
    }
}

}
```

This is the RepositoryImpl;
class UserDataRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
private val db: FirebaseFirestore,
private val storage: FirebaseStorage,
) : UserDataRepository {

```
override fun saveData(userData: UserData): Flow<Resource<FirebaseFirestore>> {

    return flow {
        // First display the loading
        emit(Resource.Loading())
        val db = db.collection(COLLECTION_NAME)
        db.document(userData.displayName)
            .set(userData)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Resource.Success(this@UserDataRepositoryImpl.db)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Resource.Error(e.message.toString(), this@UserDataRepositoryImpl.db)
            }
            .await()
        emit(Resource.Success(this@UserDataRepositoryImpl.db))

    }.catch {
        emit(Resource.Error(it.message.toString()))
    }
}


override suspend fun addImageToFirebaseStorage(imageUri: Uri): Resource<Uri> {
    return try {
        val downloadUrl = storage.reference.child(IMAGES)
            .child(PROFILE_IMAGE_NAME)
            .putFile(imageUri).await()
            .storage.downloadUrl.await()
        Resource.Success(downloadUrl)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Resource.Error(e.message.toString())
    }
}
```

Error message; E  could not locate file for uploading:
2024-01-09 22:48:36.458 22721-22721 StorageException        com.example.messageme                E  StorageException has occurred.
An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
2024-01-09 22:48:36.459 22721-22721 StorageException        com.example.messageme                E  No content provider:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider:
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1673)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1503)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1187)
at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.(UploadTask.java:153)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xab5e.jpg)
Error message is;   E  Error: An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.

I want to make sure every time I select a picture in my gallery and I click on the save button, it saves the selected image to my firebase so that I can easily call it and display it as a user's profile image in my app

Comment: What is the exact value of `imageUrl`?  You can't provide a URL to a remote object (http/https) when uploading to Firebase Storage. The file must be available locally first, which means you will likely have to write code to download it first, then upload it after that's complete.

Comment: I'm trying to select the image from my local storage then upload it to firebase storage  using;  var imageUri by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(userData.profilePictureUri) }
    val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        imageUri.ifBlank { R.drawable.ic_person }
    )
    val launcher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
    ) { uri ->
        uri?.let { imageUri = it.toString() }
    }     DisplayPicture(image = painter,)
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { launcher.launch(ALL_IMAGES) })

Comment: If you have more code to share, edit the question to add it and properly format it.  It's extremely difficult to read lots of code in a comment.

Comment: Can you please show us the line of code that produces that error? Please also respond using @AlexMamo Besides that, since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-upload-an-image-to-cloud-storage-and-save-the-url-in-firestore-42711ca1df46) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudStorageJetpackCompose). It's a working solution.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).